# iOS - How To Enable User Interaction With WebView

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a code in swift for deactivation/activation of touch clicking of button on WebView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can activate/deactivate user interaction with the `isUserInteractionEnabled` on `WKWebView`.

```
webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: This method deactivate all webView touch interactions, not only a particular layout button..

Answer (score 1):

Just to **activate/deactivate** your button you can use delegate method:

[webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidFinishLoad:)

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        let js = "document.getElementById('yourButton').disabled = true;);"
        self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(js)
}
```

But if you want to **interact with touch** to add some code supposing you have in your HTML:

```
<a class="yourButton" href="inapp://capture">Button Text</a>
```

Whith the UIWebView delegate method:

[webView(_:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:)
you can do:

```
func webView(WebViewNews: UIWebView!, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest!, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

if request.URL.scheme == "inapp" {
      if request.URL.host == "capture" {
         // do capture action and do whatever you want
      }  
      return false
   }  
   return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) if you want to activate/deactivate button of your html then you have to use method

```
stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString
```

**example**

```
func webView(WebViewNews: UIWebView!, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest!, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool 
{

    let result = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('btnname').disabled = true;")

}
```

by this method you can access your html button and can do activate/deactiavte from your webview delegate method.

2) If your button is native button then you can do by 
userInteractionEnabled property

**example**

```
webView.userInteractionEnabled = true/false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the javascript to disable that button from webview's 
[- stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:).

```
self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('myBtn').disabled = true;")
```